# Copying and Pasting Chart with Blended Source?

Tags: looker-studio

When I have a chart that uses an embedded data source, I am able to copy the chart from one report to another, as long as there are no inherited filters, and it brings the data source along with it. It brings over any filters that are applied to the chart directly and displays correctly. So that's good.

BUT when I have a chart that uses a blend (where that same embedded data source is blended on itself), I am not able to copy the chart to another report and have it appear as intended. The blend uses filters to extract certain values at different parts of the blend. When I copy the charts that use the blended source, the filters inside the blend don't seem to come along for the ride.

I need to be able to copy and paste the chart from one report to another without intervention. Any ideas?